# What and where is the iso file for 32bit architecture PC to install ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 32-bit

In order to create one USB stick with 18.04 for 32 bit, can someone tell me  where is the iso file and its name for 32bit architecture PC  to install ubuntu 18.04 as I am unable to find the exact link for 32 bit. Ubuntu desktop 18.04 is saying its for 64bit.

Comment: For me it seems that it is time to switch to traditional desktop such [as MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) (they have [32-bit ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04/release/)). Other possible way is to start from [network boot mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/) and install any desktop environment from it.

Comment: Many of the flavors provided x86 builds (and for some 18.04 LTS was their last).  Xubuntu & Lubuntu also provided 18.10 in x86, but last month (Dec 2018) they announced & stop producing 19.04 x86 builds.  Yes x86 software is still built, but fewer ISO install options now exist for x86 (alternative downloads)

Comment: @David  Foerster : As Ubuntu 14.04 is going to end, should I install Ubuntu MATE over 14.04 using code sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop in the terminal OR first remove Ubuntu 14.04 and fresh install Ubuntu MATE 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic) using its ISO image? Please suggest which way is better as need to have a secure environment going ahead on my 32 bit Dell Inspiron which is working fine till date with dual boot.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.